# Use Regex to Separate Pairs of Title and URL

Tags: python, regex

I copied a list of books and their URL from a website that becomes one string when pasted in a word doc and I'd like to separate each Title and URL on new lines:

Copied list:

> Elementary Algebra https://amzn.to/3S7yG0Y Pre-Algebra https://amzn.to/3TpW8HK Discrete Mathematical Structures https://amzn.to/3eBYogb Discrete Mathematics and its Applications https://amzn.to/3TvfThe Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics https://amzn.to/3CELUfO ...etc...

I figure the regex pattern can be something like:
any number of words (might have a hypthon or something) then http or https :// then a
mix of alphanumerics, forward slashes and periods and then a final space after the http
address to mark the location to split on.

I have this aweful looking pattern that is not capturing all the pairs:

```
\w*\s\w*\s\w*://\w*.\w*/\w*\s
```

[image]
https://regexr.com/

Also, in python it returns only the first match and I can't figure out how to group it with () and then get all of them with *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AxYlVH/1)):

```py
import re

s = """Elementary Algebra https://amzn.to/3S7yG0Y Pre-Algebra https://amzn.to/3TpW8HK Discrete Mathematical Structures https://amzn.to/3eBYogb Discrete Mathematics and its Applications https://amzn.to/3TvfThe Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics https://amzn.to/3CELUfO"""

pat = re.compile(r"\s*(.*?)\s+(https?://\S+)")

print(pat.findall(s))
```

Prints:

```
[
    ("Elementary Algebra", "https://amzn.to/3S7yG0Y"),
    ("Pre-Algebra", "https://amzn.to/3TpW8HK"),
    ("Discrete Mathematical Structures", "https://amzn.to/3eBYogb"),
    ("Discrete Mathematics and its Applications", "https://amzn.to/3TvfThe"),
    ("Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics", "https://amzn.to/3CELUfO"),
]
```

Comment: regex101 is excellent! I'm having trouble understanding why the ? is necessary after .* in (.*?)   I see that it changes the behavior of * from matching the previous token as many times as possible to as few times as possible.